# Mean and Standard Deviation in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have different csv file in a folder and I want to calculate the mean and the standard deviation of H2S and CO2 values (the thrid and fourth columns). Here's my example file:

Time SO2 H2S CO2 Rh Tair Pressure VBatt

```
27/03/17 02:02 -0.06295014 124.748.880.993.867 5.278.368 8.715.702 1.570.249 862.8 1.382.667
27/03/17 02:02 -0.07086754 12.474.390.019.852 4.843.832 8.717.385 15.703 862.8 137.486
27/03/17 02:02 -0.07969666 12.473.647.121.563 4.773.366 8.718.224 1.570.264 862.8 1.376.822 ...
```

I've tried to write this script but I can't go ahead:

```
for csvfile in glob('/Users/silviamassaro/concentrazioni_gas/CS/*.csv'):
    #print(csvfile)
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f: 
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for row_index, row in enumerate(r): 
            for col_index, data in enumerate(row):
                print(row_index, col_index, data)
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('/Users/silviamassaro/concentrazioni_gas/CS/*.csv')

dataset[['H2S', 'CO2']].mean()
dataset[['H2S', 'CO2']].std()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python pandas for reading csv into a dataframe and perform statistical analysis.

```py
import pandas as pd

concentrazioni = pd.read_csv('/Users/silviamassaro/concentrazioni_gas/CS/*.csv')
concentrazioni.mean(axis=0)
concentrazioni.std(axis=0)
```

Comment: Many thanks!! But when I try this I found the following error: 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/Users/silviamassaro/Documents/INGV_BOLO/GUADELOUPE/DISGAS_sim/flussi&concentrazioni_VALIDAZIONE/concentrazioni_gas/CS/*.csv' does not exist: b'/Users/silviamassaro/Documents/INGV_BOLO/GUADELOUPE/DISGAS_sim/flussi&concentrazioni_VALIDAZIONE/concentrazioni_gas/CS/*.csv'